# How to write “independent and identically distributed” symbol in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

How can I write the symbol below using MS Word equation editor?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpL5i.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the current ("new") equation editor, the problem is that it only really supports stretchy "underbrace" characters, not stretchy tilde characters.

The closest I can get is to enter the following (in linear mode)

```
\matrix(i.i.d.@~)
```

then select the tilde and click the "Normal text" button ("abc Normal Text" in the Equation Editor's Design ribbon (or the "abc" button in the Mac Word 2011 version), then change the font size of the"~" to, say, 36 or 48pt. What that actually does is to insert a couple of double quotation marks around the tilde and avoids changing the font size of the entire expression.

The tilde is obviously out of proportion and rather thick, but it does at least span the "i.i.d." reasonably well. If you can use "iid" instead of "i.i.d." then the tilde could be smaller - maybe 24pt.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a simple edit of a built-in operator.

1. In the Equation ribbon, in the **Operator** drop-down, under the **Common Operator Structures** section, select the operator that says **yields** over an arrow.
2. Convert your equation to use **Linear** mode: from the ribbon, click the **Convert** drop-down, then click **Current - Linear**.
3. Delete the word **yields** and replace it with **"i.i.d."** (actually type the quotation marks so the text is displayed in Text mode)
4. Delete the **→** (arrow) and replace with a **~** (tilde).
5. Convert your equation back to **Professional** mode.

Here's an illustration of the steps:
[image]

This works for me in Word for Microsoft 365 (version 2102).

Answer (score 0):

While writing your equation, simply use:

```
\sim \above iid
```

Remember to hit space (as in the code) after every command so that it gets rendered without interference from other commands.

Example: `X \sim \above iid \scriptN (0, 1)` gives you this

[image]

i.e. $$X \sim \above iid \scriptN (0, 1)$$